# Is it possible to load Dired+ automatically with use-package?

Tags: init-file, dired, use-package

I'm trying to add `dired+` to my `init.el` with `use-package` but I can't seem to find the name of `dired+` on any of the package repositories ( marmalade, melpa or elpa  ).

I'd been able to add `dired+` after manually downloading it and activating it with `require` and defining the location with `load-path`.

Current code on init.el for loading `dired+` after manually download:

```
;; ---- Dired + --------
;; Loads Dired+ Manually
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/dired+/")
(require 'dired+)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dired+` has left MELPA repository, and now you have to [download](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el) it manually from EmacsWiki. You can still use `use-package` with a downloaded package, like this:

```
(use-package dired+
  :load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages/dired+")
```

Another option is to use a `dired+` repository mirror in github, along with a tool like [quelpa](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa-use-package), which allows you to fetch packages directly from a repository:

```
(use-package dired+
  :quelpa (dired+ :fetcher github :repo "emacsmirror/dired-plus"))
```

Comment: The first option assumes you have created the directory: `~/.emacs.d/packages/dired+/` which holds `dired+.el` file. I know it is implicit, since `load-path` refers to a path for directories, but just in case anyone come here and do a quick copy&paste... like I did...

Comment: If you use `use-package` with `straight` then `(use-package dired+)` is enough.